# Install SpeechRecognition in Raspberry [python]

Tags: python-3.x, installation, speech-recognition, raspberry-pi3

I installed the SpeechRecognition as instructed at https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition

`pip install SpeechRecognition`

Currently I use python 3.5 on my Raspberry Pi 3. The installation has no errors.
The next part of the tutorial says that: "To quickly try it out, run `python -m speech_recognition` after installing." But it seems that the library was not found.

[image]

It looks like the system is looking for a library somewhere else or I have misplaced the library. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was solved when running `python3 -m speech_recognition`.

Answer (score 1):

Try
`pip3 install SpeechRecognition`

Comment: I'm using python3.5 as the default. So the pip is equivalent to pip3

Comment: Also my installation is successful. Help me to run this package rather than installing it

Comment: when you run `pip freeze` can you see SpeechRecognition module in list?

Comment: My problem was solved when running `python3 -m speech_recognition`. Thank for your help

Comment: "pip" is for Python 2, "pip3" is indeed for Python 3. Likewise, "python" is Python 2 and "python3" is Python 3.